# What word describes the unique possibilities when disambiguating a word?

Tags: english, terminology

The [disambiguation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_(disambiguation)) for the word `turtle` on wikipedia displays a list of possibilities to choose from.

Many of these possibilities are just the same word `turtle` but with different meanings.

Considering just those entries that are the same word `turtle` but with different meanings, is there a noun for the word and one of it's possible meanings?

Said another way, the precise term for an unambiguous pairing of a word and one of its possible meanings together.

I thought `term` might be close to what I was looking for but the answer to [What is the difference between a term and a word?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/146450/what-is-the-difference-between-a-term-and-a-word/146455) seemed to indicate that `term` wouldn't be the right word.

Generically the word meaning might work as you could say a word has X number of meanings and if I sum up the X for every word in a language I would get the total possible meanings expressed by all words in that language.

I would like a more precise technical term than meaning(s) if there is one.

Comment: It's called a *reading* or *sense* of the word.

Comment: I read in another question that the pair of signifier and signified (going back to Saussure, if I remember correctly) is just defined as a word. Later I read that the terminology isn't precise. Arguably we might say both that true homonyms are different words or the same word, as a matter of polysemy. If you need the answer for writing a paper, just declare your own prefered definition.